# Mutation Observer or DOMNodeInserted

Tags: javascript

I have a script where I´ve use on the first slide of Adobe Captivate, to automate the task ok creating, courses, the script create the UX, navigation elements, intro/end motions, a game, insert spritesheets with characters, etc...

I´ve used DOMNodeInserted until know to check the modifications on the slide, when the user go to the next slide, the elements are added to the DOM and the page content is changed I´ve used this timer until now to call the function:

```js
function detectChange(){
 var slideName = document.getElementById('div_Slide')
 slideName.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", detectChange, false); 
    updateSlideElements();
    setTimeout(updateSlideElements, 100);
}
```

So I´m trying to use mutation Observer now:

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    updateSlideElements();
});

observer.observe(document.getElementById('div_Slide').firstChild, {
    attributes: true,
    childList:true
});
```

But this is what´s happening, before with setTimeout I could reach the following element:

```js
var motionText2 = document.querySelectorAll('div[id*=motion][class=cp-accessibility]');
```

This element is the firstChild of:

[image]

And the element can be found:

[image]

But now with mutationObserver the console returns empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I´ve just use a setTimeout inside the observer and watch the parent container not the firstChild:

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    setTimeout(updateSlideElements, 100);
});
observer.observe(document.getElementById('div_Slide'), {
    attributes: true,
    childList:true
    //subtree:true
});
```